# PySpark Create new column from transformations in another dataframe

Tags: dataframe, design-patterns, pyspark, functional-programming, apache-spark-sql

Looking for a more functional and computationally efficient approach in PySpark ->

I have master table (containing billions of rows), the columns of interests are:

id - (String),

tokens - (Array(string))- ex, ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma']

-- (Calling it dataframe, df1)

I have another summary table which contains top 25 tokens like:

-- (Calling it dataframe, df2)
Ex:

### Token

Alpha

Beta

Zi

Mu

Now to this second table (or, dataframe), I wish to append a row which contains a list of ids for that token from the first table, so that the result looks like:

### Token       Ids

Alpha       [1, 2, 3]

Beta        [3, 5, 6, 8, 9]

Zi          [2, 8, 12]

Mu          [1, 15, 16, 17]

**Present Approach:**

From the df2, figure out the distinct tokens and store it as a list (say l1).

```
(For every token from list, l1):
    Filter df1 to extract the unique ids as a list, call it l2
    Add this new list (l2) as a new column (Ids) to the dataframe (df2) to create a new dataframe (df3)
    persist df3 to a table
```

I agree this is a terribe approach and for any given l1 with 100k records, it will run forever. Can anyone help me rewrite the code (for Pyspark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alternatively attempt to join both the table on a new column which would essentially contain only the tokens exploded to the individual rows. That would be helpful from both computational efficiency, allocated resources and the required processing time.

Additionally, there are several in-the-box join privileges including 'map-side join' which would further propel your cause.

Comment: How about other join advantages I can exploit here?

Comment: Kindly attempt the following change in the hive configurations: Setting hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin to true.

Comment: Kindly attempt the following change in the hive configurations: Setting hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin.sortedmerge to true.

Comment: Kindly attempt the following change in the hive configurations: Setting hive.input.format to org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.BucketizedHiveInputFormat.

Answer (score 0):

`Explode` the `tokens` array column of `df1` and then `join` with `df2` (left join) with *lower case of tokens and token* and then `groupBy` token and collect the `id`s as set

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
#exolode tokens column for joining with df2
df1 = df1.withColumn('tokens', f.explode('tokens'))

#left join with case insensitive and collecting ids as set for each token
df2.join(df1, f.lower(df1.tokens) == f.lower(df2.token), 'left')\
    .groupBy('token')\
    .agg(f.collect_set('id').alias('ids'))\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

I hope the answer is helpful